# How to scale a sprite image without losing color key information?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, image, animation, directdraw

I'm currently developing a simple application that displays map and draws some markers on it. I'm developing for Windows Mobile, so I decided to use DirectDraw and Imaging interfaces to make the application fast and pretty. The map moves when user moves finger on the touchscreen, so the whole map moving/scrolling animation has to be fast, but it is not.

On every map update I have to draw portion of the map, control buttons, and markers - buttons and markers are preloaded on DirectDraw surface as a mipmap. So the only thing I do is BitBlit from the mipmap to a back buffer, and from the back buffer to a primary surface (I can't use page flipping due to the windowed mode of my application).

Previously I used premultiplied-alpha surface with 32 bit ARGB pixel format for images mipmap, everything was looking good, but drawing entire "scene" was horribly slow - i could forget about smooth map scrolling. Now I'm using mipmap with native (RGB565) pixel format and fuchsia (0xFF00FF) color key. Drawing is much better.

My mipmap surface is generated on program loading - images are loaded from files, scaled (with filtering) and drawn on mipmap. The problem is, that image scaling process blends pixel colors, and those pixels which are on the border of a sprite region are blended with surrounding fuchsia pixels resulting semi-fuchsia color that is not treated as color key. When I do blitting with color key option, sprites have small fuchsia-like borders, and it looks really bad.

How to solve this problem? I can use alpha blitting, but it is too slow - even in ARGB 1555 format.

Comment: OK, I've found a solution.
1) I load images with resizing and filtering onto a temporary alpha surface
2) I lock surface and get a direct pointer to a surface memory
3) Scan ARGB pixels and overwrite pixels which are semitransparent with 0x00000000 color
4) Unlock surface and do an AlphaBlt of the surface content onto the real mipmap surface (filled with fuchsia color)
5) Use Blt with color key
6) Have fun:)